# Is to, of course, have | Split infinitive

Tags: infinitives

Is it possible to split the "to" from the verb in this example:

[image]

Is it correct? Does it sound strange to your ears?

Comment: Hello, mim. What do Google 5-grams for ['is of course to have' & 'is to of course have'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+of+course+to+have%2Cis+to+of+course+have&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20of%20course%20to%20have%3B%2Cc0) strongly suggest?

Comment: *It's very, of course, strange. _Of course_, like other parenthetic expressions, should be inserted only at constituent boundaries. That includes _to_ + Infinitive constituents, and others, too. Consider *_These are the, of course, times that try men's souls,_ or *_I didn't recognize, of course, him_ .